# Is license in openam sourcecode can be used in production enviornment

Tags: openam

We are using openam12.0.0  build and install from openAm12 tag build source code from SVN repo.

my question is, the license present in source code can be used in production
environment, or what type of license we need for production for using openAM

I had check form forgerock they give  for development

```
CDDL-1.0 licence
```

Common Development and Distribution License (CDDL) 1.0. This license applies to OpenAM source code as indicated in the sources themselves.

can this license be used for production enviornment ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CDDL license has no such restrictions, only the ForgeRock binary license has those. If you are building the source code on your own, then only CDDL will apply meaning that you should be able to use it in production environments without a problem.

Comment: Thanks, peter for reply back ,

Comment: Hi Peter,
If we use Openam 10.0.0 binary from forgerock in production, do we still need to purchase license ?

Comment: If you can find the binary license in the WAR file, then yes, but to my knowledge 10.0.0 didn't have it. On the other hand 10.0.0 is almost fully EOSL'd, you really shouldn't use it.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed. The OpenAM binary can be used in test environments for free but not in production. I've built 11 and 12, both the servers and the Tomcat agents, from source. As long as you know Java, Maven, and SVN, it shouldn't be too bad.

Comment: how was your experience with custom built OpenAM?

Comment: I've had it running in production for almost 2 years now and have not experienced any problems that I can attribute to the custom build. The only real problem I've had is stale LDAP password caching, which is rare and intermittent. Tomcat agents are problem free. Over a dozen apps are using the agent. For the most part it has been setup and forget. Need to consider upgrading to the newer version though.

Comment: I cannot comment on the IDP Proxy feature specifically, but I have used OpenAM SAML as an IdP. I've used it with open source CRM products, commercial remote hosted SPs, and commercial self hosted SPs. It's takes some tweaking, but I eventually got it working. OpenAM writes SAML attributes to the LDAP accounts so the account needs write access too and you need to modify the LDAP schema. Assuming your using LDAP, of course.

Comment: That's great. Did you use remote SP for your applications, how did you manage SP to application communication? About LDAP, actually I need to use database for authentication so I probably need to use JAAS with OpenAM.

Comment: For my apps, I just used the OpenAM Tomcat Agent, not SAML. You basically just add a filter to the filter chain. Never used JAAS with OpenAM, but it looks like they support it so hopefully you're good.